# Diseño tabla JTable Java Swing - Netbeans

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola estoy insertado datos de una base de datos en una tabla gracias a una consulta `SQL` y agregando los datos a un `Object[][]`. Con ese `Object[][]` los integro gracias a `DefaultTableModel` a un `JTable`. Se integran perfectamente pero se ve mal a vista interfaz del usuario. ¿Cómo podría ajustarse la tabla a los datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No has probado a hacer las columnas y el `JScrollPane` más grandes?

Comment: El JScrollPane sí, pero las columnas no sé como modificarlas el tamaño. Desde Propiedades no encontré nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar el tamaño de las columnas debes usar:

```
tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(model.findColumn("NombreColumna")).setPreferredWidth(50);
```

Esto cambiará el ancho a 50 de la columna con la cabecera "NombreColumna".

Comment: table_alquilados.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(260); //Bastidor
        table_alquilados.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(140); //Color
        así sucesivamente

Comment: Si no cambias el orden de las columnas, ni usas el índice buscado por nombre en ninguna parte más del código también te sirve lo de tu comentario.

Comment: Ya me funciona, muchas gracias. Además añadí el evento ActionPerformed por cada botón para que muestre los datos de cada opción. Lo malo que las tablas no tienen la misma cantidad de datos(filas), es decir, alquilados tiene 10 filas y no alquilados tiene 8 filas, en la tabla de "no alquilados" me encuadra el borde inferior como si fueran de 10 filas y no de 8.